# Apply comica stamp effect on video using after effect

Tags: effects, adobe-after-effects, video

In `comica - video filters` android app there are some effects like `STAMP` effect.

[image]

Now I want to apply this effect on my videos using `after effect` in pc.
How can I do this? Are there any effect like this for after effect? or are there exactly this effect for after effect?

Comment: Probably better answered at http://video.stackexchange.com

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Video editing is off-topic here. Try Video Production Stack Exchange.